# Catch exception in Pool worker that is not started yet

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to catch exception in sub process. My code (see below) works fine if number of workers == number of tasks. But if workers more than tasks as in an example, 2 process that was not started yet will thow same exception but I can't catch it neither in MainProcess nor in sub processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
import time
from exceptions import GracefulExit
import signal


def terminate_handler(signum, frame):
    print(dir(frame))
    if current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
        # we will not raise error if process
        # is main because we need to finish all the jobs
        return
    raise GracefulExit()


def test_func(val):
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            i += 1
            if i >= 10:
                return i
    except GracefulExit:
        pass
    return i


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(
            signal.SIGINT, terminate_handler)
    try:
        with Pool(5) as p:
            r = p.map(test_func, [1, 2, 3])
    except GracefulExit:
        pass
    print(r)
```

Comment: couldn't you just make a `GracefulExit()` function which handles the exit, instead of raising an exception?

Comment: Then I should use some syncronization structure to control if ctrl+c is pressed. It is possible but much slower. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What can I suggest, pick any variant:

1. make sure that number of tasks not less the number of workers, just add stubs (e.g. `None`) to ensure that all workers will start
2. override `run` method of Pool's Process:

   ```
   class CustomProcess(Process):
       def run(self):
           try:
               super().run()
           except GracefulExit:
               print('interrupted idle worker')


   class CustomPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
       Process = CustomProcess

   ....

   with CustomPool(5) as p:
      r = p.map(test_func, [1, 2, 3])
   ```
3. write your own pool implementation